# How to properly secure my rest endpoints in jhipster?

Tags: jhipster

I would like to secure my rest endpoints in the backend. For example an author can query his books like this:

> /books?authorId=5&login=username

```
@GetMapping("/books")
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<List<Book>> getAllBooks(
        @RequestParam(value="authorId", required = false) String authorId, 
        @RequestParam(value="login", required = false) String login) {
    if(!login.equals(SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin().get())){
        return ResponseEntity.status(401).build();
    }
    List<Book> result;
    if(authorId!= null)
        result = bookService.findByAuthorId(authorId);
    else if("admin".equals(SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin().get()))
        result = bookService.findAll();
    else return ResponseEntity.status(401).build();
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(result);
}
```

Preferable I would like to only pass the authorId in the params

> /books?authorId=5

but since SecurityUtils only gives me the loginName I can't compare them and identify the user in the backend.

Also since it's a microservice I can't access the AccountService.java which is handled by the gateway.

It all works fine but it seems wrong? Is there a better way to allow certain querys only for certain users? Should I make another rest endpoint which handles specifally requests to get books for specific users?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are addressing 2 use cases: one for authors (list my books) and one for management (list all books) for security reasons but usually you may also want to return different data based on use case. It could be a good idea to have 2 different resources: /api/my_books for authors and /api/books for management, you could even use nested resources.

For returning different data (also for security reasons) you can use the DTO option of JHipster with a service layer to map them from entities rather than exposing entities in your REST controllers.

Also don't pass the user id as a request param, you should modify TokenProvider to add it to the token as a claim. If you don't want to add user id to the token, you should modify book entity in your service so that it references user login rather than internal id, as long as it is immutable it does not make a difference.

Comment: I guess this makes the most sense. I just dont like that I need to send  the loginName aswell for authentification purposes. Is it possible to read the account id from the json web token?